# Printing issue on Ender 3V2

Tags: creality-ender-3

I am trying to print a fairly simple object yet I keep getting the same issue.

As you can see in the picture the print quality is bad with all the blobs on the vertical part of the print.

I have leveled the bed many times and I keep getting this issue. I have also calibrated the E-steps. I have replaced the PTFE tube as well.

I am printing with Sunlu PLA+. I was printing at 220 °C but now that I set it at 200 °C the result is a little bit better but it has not gone away.

Please advise on how to fix this.

Note: I have 2 Ender 3 V2's and the other printer is printing the same files pretty much perfect.

[image]

Comment: 220 degrees is way too high for PLA+

Answer (score 2):

1. Print the same file, with the same settings, on both machines.
2. If the problem persists, try swapping the filament between the two printers. If the problem now occurs on the other printer, that suggests that the filament is the issue. Label the bad one "For lumpy prints" and put it away.
3. If the problem persists on the printer where it first occurred, despite swapping filament reels, the issue probably has something to do with the printer. Remove and examine the nozzle, and consider replacing it even if it looks OK. Nozzles are cheap and easy to replace, so this is an easy early step.
4. If a new nozzle doesn't fix it, other parts related to the extruder like the hot end thermistor, fans, heater block, etc. could be to blame. If the thermistor is just positioned a little differently than on the "good" printer, for example, it might be reading a little low and causing the nozzle to heat up more to get to the target reading. That doesn't necessarily mean that you have to replace those parts; you just need to recognize the difference and compensate for it when you use that printer. Just as a baker might think "the recipe says 400 °F, but I know my oven runs hot, so I'll use 375 °F instead," you may need to adjust the nozzle temperature to compensate for the hardware differences when you use this printer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's only about the slicer settings, it's over extruding problem. I recommend lowering the extrusion multiplier.